# Using Python to Print Folder Sizes from Directory into CSV or Excel File

Tags: python, excel, csv, directory, export-to-excel

I currently have the python script to "print" the folder sizes of a directory in cmd. This works well.

```
import locale
import os

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")

def get_size(state, root, names):
    paths = [os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, n)) for n in names]
    # handles dangling symlinks
    state[0] += sum(os.stat(p).st_size for p in paths if os.path.exists(p))

def print_sizes(root):
    total = 0
    paths = []
    state = [0]
    n_ind = s_ind = 0
    for name in sorted(os.listdir(root)):
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            continue

        state[0] = 0
        os.path.walk(path, get_size, state)
        total += state[0]
        s_size = locale.format('%8.0f', state[0], 3)
        n_ind = max(n_ind, len(name), 5)
        s_ind = max(s_ind, len(s_size))
        paths.append((name, s_size))

    for name, size in paths:
        print name.ljust(n_ind), size.rjust(s_ind), 'bytes'
    s_total = locale.format('%8.0f', total, 3)
    print '\ntotal'.ljust(n_ind), s_total.rjust(s_ind), 'bytes'

print_sizes('.')
```

Below is a picture of the cmd result (Note that the 2012,2013,etc are folders in my target directory):

[image]

I'm wondering **how to get this data into a usable format in an Excel or CSV file.** Ideally I'm looking for a way to "print" this to excel with the folders in column A and bytes in column B.

Thanks,
JK29

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are just fields with commas separating them. Easiest thing is to open a file and write lines to it. Wherever you have a 'print' statement, append the string you're printing to a variable. Something like:

```
csv_contents = "Name,Bytes"
```

then in your second 'for' loop:

```
csv_contents += "%s,%s\n" % (name.ljust(n_ind), size.rjust(s_ind))
```

At finally at the end:

```
fp = open(output_file, "w")
fp.write(csv_contents)
fp.close()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Justin, thanks for your reply! I must say that I'm more of a noob than you probably thought. I'm having a had time setting up my code with your suggestions. 

Where do I put the csv_contents = "Name,Bytes"

Do I replace print with "csv_contents += "%s,%s\n" % (name.ljust(n_ind), size.rjust(s_ind))" ? 

Do I have to define "output_file" somewhere else in my code?

Comment: You can put the csv_contents = "Name,Bytes" somewhere toward the top of your 'print_sizes' method, it just need to happen once to initialize the variable and put a header for your two columns. You can replace the print statement if you wish, or you could keep it so that you still get a visual on what your output will be like. You should define 'output_file' somewhere at the top of your function as well. output_file = "N:\directory_sizes.csv" or something I'd guess.